# imageview setImageBitmap/setImageDrawable not working after upgrading library

Tags: android, imageview

Im using the following code:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(firstPageAddress);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Ive also tried using this code:

```
mImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(firstPageAddress));
```

firstPageAddress - path to a jpg file in the external storage of the device.

the result in both cases are the same :
[my imageview drawable after setImage in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dciIV.png)
(after pressing ViewBitmap i see the correct image)

before i upgraded libraries version everything worked fine.

i used :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

now im using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

any ideas ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
new AsyncTask<Bitmap, Bitmap, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                try {

                URL url = new URL("https://static.pexels.com/photos/3247/nature-forest-industry-rails.jpg");
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    return image;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            }
        }.execute();
```

Comment: after reading your answer i tried to do the decoding on background thread as you did, the result is the same, the image is still not shown. notice that the decoding is from a file and not from a url. i edited the question so it will be more clear.